# How to deploy Symfony 5 application on Heroku

Tags: php, linux, apache, symfony, heroku

I used these 2 sites to help me:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-symfony4
- https://medium.com/@mallle/deploy-a-symfony-5-app-to-heroku-with-the-cleardb-mysql-addon-4df64beed9d0

On my Heroku dashboard everything is ok, it says :

> Build succeeded.

But when I open the app I get a

> 403 Forbidden error.
>   You don't have permission to access this resource.

Then i ran

```
heroku logs --num 10
```

Complete result in console :

```
2020-04-02T10:56:12.107189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/" host=portefolio-symfony.herokuapp.com request_id=0c0a08dd- 
5c11-4489-88e6-7d5246f38b09 fwd="176.189.137.142" dyno=web.1 
connect=0ms service=1ms status=403 bytes=363 protocol=https
2020-04-02T10:56:12.107944+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu Apr 02 
10:56:12.107237 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 161:tid 139621535053568] 
[client 10.32.165.53:18173] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No 
matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and 
server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, 
referer: https://dashboard.heroku.com/
2020-04-02T10:56:12.108260+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.32.165.53 - - 
[02/Apr/2020:10:56:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 199 
"https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 
Safari/537.36
2020-04-02T11:30:01.272965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-04-02T11:30:01.350792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up 
to down
2020-04-02T11:30:02.554326+00:00 app[web.1]: SIGTERM received, 
attempting graceful shutdown...
2020-04-02T11:30:02.554551+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping php-fpm...
2020-04-02T11:30:02.556082+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping httpd 
gracefully...
2020-04-02T11:30:02.556083+00:00 app[web.1]: Stopping httpd...
2020-04-02T11:30:02.635664+00:00 app[web.1]: Shutdown complete.
```

I saw that it could be from the .htaccess file in the public/ directory

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_alias.c>
      RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/

   </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Here the Procfile :

`'web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/'`

Comment: Ok now it's works, i have deploy my app on Heroku, but without any style. 
I think my problem is **Webpack**. I remove in this 2 helpers Twig in base.html.twig `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
 
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find a solution ! Here are the details to help you if you need it.

In **base.html.twig**

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

Then I put at the end the script tag

```
{% block javascripts %}
  {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

In **.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
   RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
   RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
   RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_alias.c>

     RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

In **app.js** I've added this line :

```
require('../css/app.scss');
```

In **webpack.config.js** :

```
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath("public/build/")
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath("/build")
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images'
    })

    .addEntry("app", "./assets/js/app.js")
```

In **package.json** I've added this line to :

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "encore production --progress"
 },
```

The **Procfile** only this line

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

And finally in Heroku > Settings > **Config Vars**

- NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
- NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
- YARN_PRODUCTION=false

Heroku > Settings > Buildpack

- heroku/nodejs
- heroku/php

Here a link that I used to help me again

- https://medium.com/@jontorrado/deploying-a-symfony-4-application-to-heroku-with-webpack-abdf7771cde9